# Is there a way to search an SQL database for rows with specific relations?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to formulate an SQL query that can be used to retrieve the employees that manage specific clients. I have a three-database structure, one table for employees and one for clients, with a third table connecting the ID's. For example, when I want to search for the employees that manage clients Jeff and Bill, I would first try the following:

```
SELECT e.name FROM employees e JOIN manages m ON e.emp_id = m.emp_id JOIN clients c ON m.cli_id = c.cli_id
WHERE c.cli_name = 'Jeff' AND c.cli_name = 'Bill';
```

However, there's an obvious logical flaw in this query, as it tries to find a row where two mutually exclusive facts are true. I've tried to solve this by grouping by employee name and checking which groups have these properties, but it doesn't seem to work. There must be some way to make this work, but I've not managed to find it online. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregation.  Assuming no duplicates:

```
SELECT e.name
FROM employees e JOIN
     manages m 
     ON e.emp_id = m.emp_id JOIN 
     clients c
      ON m.cli_id = c.cli_id
WHERE c.cli_name IN ('Jeff', 'Bill')   -- match names with both clients
GROUP BY e.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;                   -- keep only names that have two matches
```